# count number of lines from several files and store count from all text files into one variable using for loop

Tags: bash, awk

I want to count number of lines from many text files and then store them into a variable to find the lowest number. I am trying to do this in for loop but it stores only the result from last text file in loop.

```
 for txt in home/data/*.txt
 do
       count_txt=$(cat $txt | wc -l) | bc

 done
```

Thanks

Comment: How about if no file exists?

Answer (score 1):

give this one-liner a try:

```
wc -l /path/*.txt|awk 'NR==1{m=$1}{m=($1*1)<m?($1*1):m}END{print m}'
```

Comment: could you please explain this. I don't have much knowledge of awk

Comment: @hash awk read the first column of wc -l output, which is the numbers, and pick the smallest number and print out.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=(home/data/*.txt) LOWEST_COUNT='N/A' FILE=''
[[ ${#FILES[@]} -gt 0 ]] && read -r LOWEST_COUNT FILE < <(exec wc -l "${FILES[@]}" | sort -n)
echo "$LOWEST_COUNT | $FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need something like this (using GNU awk for ENDFILE):

```
awk 'ENDFILE{min = (min < FNR ? min : FNR)} END{print min}' home/data/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

*Update : According to EdMorton comment, **awk is the right tool** to use to solve this kind of problem, this approach isn't a final implementation and it fails for some filenames ( like filenames with spaces ),to conclude, **awk** is way more performant and reliable*

If you want to use a for loop, you can do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX="0"
MIN="INIT"
for F in home/data/*.txt
do
    NBLINE=$(cat $F | wc -l)
    if [[ "$NBLINE" -gt "$MAX"  ]] ; then
            MAX="$NBLINE"
            BIG_FILE="$F"
    fi
    if [[ "$MIN" == "INIT" ]] ; then
            MIN="$NBLINE"
            SMA_FILE="$F"
    fi
    if [[ "$NBLINE" -lt "$MIN" ]] ; then
            MIN="$NBLINE"
            SMA_FILE="$F"
    fi
done
echo "File = $BIG_FILE  -- Lines = $MAX"
echo "File = $SMA_FILE  -- Lines = $MIN"
exit
```

Comment: This will output the maximal number of lines, not the minimal.

Comment: There's still a typo :) `[[ "$NBLINE" -lt "$MAX" ]] `, should be `$MIN`. You could also concatenate both of your tests to improve readability (try `[[ "$MIN" == "INIT" || "$NBLINE" -lt "$MIN" ]]` )

Comment: This is the wrong approach. In addition to being very slow, it will fail in various ways given various file names and contents. The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate text files is awk. Just call awk.

Comment: @EdMorton i agree with you, awk should be used in this case and it has a way more better performance and reliability, i just tried to help him continuing his approach, i'll update my answer for the others